# SSRS Report bookmark navigation causes left shift in HTML (Sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS 2008R2 report being accessed in SharePoint Integrated Mode.  The report has multip0le sections, each with its own tablix, and uses bookmarks to assist with paging through multiple sections (e.g. if section 1 has 6 pages and the user wants to jump directly to section 2, they would click my bookmark to jump directly to page 7 where section 2 starts).

When the user clicks a bookmark, they jump to the correct section, but the page is shifted to the left, sometimes so far that it looks blank because the report body has been completely scrolled off the screen.  However, when the user uses the standard page navigation buttons on the toolbar, each section displays correctly (no left shift).  This happens only when viewing on the SharePoint Reporting site.  The behavior doesn't show up the Visual Studio development tool.

Each report section is inside a rectangle container which is use as the bookmark and to control forced page breaks between the sections.

At first I thought it may be related to the control where I placed the bookmark, so I moved the bookmarks around to other controls, but that didn't work.  Then I thought it may be related to the tablix being wider than the page, but some sections are wider than the page but the shift doesn't occur.

Has anyone seen this behavior or have any ideas on how to fix it?  I've done several Google searches, but haven't had any luck finding a similar situation.

I have images of what I'm describing, however, I don't appear to have enough reputation points to post them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your report have any elements that go very far to the right? It's possible some element has pushed the margin out really far but isn't actually displaying for some reason. Check how the report renders to PDF and see if it is spitting out a lot of blank pages in between content.